# Start infinite loop thread when button is pressed, stop when it is pressed again

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am simulating a camera feed and have a button that goes through an infinite loop of images.
It starts when the button is clicked, when the button is clicked it is supposed to stop the thread until the button is clicked again.

Right now it starts and loops fine, but when I click it again It crashes

on click

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
       switch(v.getId()){

       case R.id.cam1btn:{
         if(thread1 == null){
           thread1 = new Thread(){
                public void run(){
                  Cam1();
                }
            };
            thread1.start();

         }
         else
         {
             thread1.stop();
             thread1=(null);
         }

       }
       break;
```

Cam1 function

```
protected void Cam1() {
    int i=0;

    do{
        System.out.println("got into  loop");
        for(int x=0;x<4;x++){

            //imgFeed1.setImageAlpha(camFeed1[x]);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final int temp = x;
            mCam1Handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    imgFeed1.setImageResource(camFeed1[temp]);
                }
            });

            }

    }while(i == 0);


}
```

logcat

[image: logcat]

Comment: Says sorry but this app has stopped working

Comment: try `thread1.interrupt()` instead of `thread1.stop()`

Comment: Do not use `Thread.stop()`, it is deprecated for very good reasons.

Comment: tried it, the thread keeps looping now

Answer (score 0):

You should not forcibly stop the thread in general. Thread has to stop by completing its task.

In your case, you need to define `i = 0` in a instance scope and set that to some value when user clicks stop button, with that your while loop ends and the thread completes its task.

I would rather suggest you to maintain a `boolean` flag instead of an `int`.

**UPDATE**
Okay, then your you should have a flag and toggle that ex: `toRun = false` for the first time, when the user clicks the button you do `toRun = !toRun;`. In your run method there should be a `while(toRun) { 
   //repeat your task
 }`

Comment: there is no stop button, just one button that starts the loop, when it is clicked again the thread is supposed to stop, then start again after clicking it again and so on

Answer (score 0):

just to help you understand Rp- answer:

first declare boolean `toRun` outside your `thread` because it is a variable that is accessed by two threads(UI and your created) you must use 'synchornize` block to access it and read and write it.

```
boolean toRun = false;

public void onClick(View v) {
   switch(v.getId()){

   case R.id.cam1btn:{
     boolean isThreadRunning;
     synchronize(toRun){
       isThreadRunning = toRun;   
    }

     if(!isThreadRunning){
       toRun =true; // here you do not need synchronize block because the thread has not been created.
       thread1 = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
              Cam1();
            }
        };
        thread1.start();

     }
     else
     {
         synchornize(toRun){
             toRun = false;
         }
     }

   }
   break;
```

and in your cam1:

```
 protected void Cam1() {
   boolean myRun;

    do{
        System.out.println("got into  loop");
        for(int x=0;x<4;x++){

            //imgFeed1.setImageAlpha(camFeed1[x]);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            final int temp = x;
            mCam1Handler.post(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    imgFeed1.setImageResource(camFeed1[temp]);
                }
            });

            }

    synchronize(toRun){
       myRun = toRun;   
    }
    }while(myRun);

}
```

Comment: starts fine and loops through but when I hit the button again it continues to loop through to the first image and stops. When I hit the button again after that it doesn't do anything.

Comment: explain `it continues to loop through to the first image and stops.` more because i do not understand

Comment: I think I have a logic issue with the loop. camFeed1 is an int array that has the id of five different images. After I hit the button to stop the thread it will continue to loop through that id array until it reaches camFeed1[0] and then will stop. Thank you for your help, I am going to call it a night and work through it tommorow

Comment: `When I hit the button again after that it doesn't do anything.` i changed first code block to solve that look at answer again